# Is LTSP and ThinClients still live?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, raspberry-pi, thin-client

I want to setup thin client on my fat client with **Linux Mint 18** with **Raspberry Pi** thin clients and have two question about it.

1. I searched and see [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/) but it seems latest news on site was posted on 2013, so is it stable for using or LTSP replaced with other alternatives?
2. Also I see [berryterminal](http://www.berryterminal.com/) for Raspberry Pi thin client side and it's [source](https://github.com/maxnet/berryterminal) also not maintained until 2013, so is it OK to using Raspberry Pi as a thin client or not?

Comment: I can't see a problem with using a Pi for this but the ARM chipset does limit your options a little.

Comment: @Burgi Thanks for your attention. Which limitation you mean? Is LTSP project still live?

Comment: I mean you can't use a standard Linux distro, you will have to use one compiled to work on the Pi CPU.

Comment: It's right but when I want use Pi just as a thin client then I think it's not very important for example is Rasebian can use as a thin client OS to connect to Mint on host?